# Colon in quotes in Shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to create an alias like this.

```
alias foo='function bar(){echo "$1:localhost"};bar'
```

But when I execute `foo 123`, it shows `123ocalhost`, so `:l` is missing.

I also tried `alias foo='function bar(){echo "$1:a"};bar'`. Executing `foo 123` produces `/current_directory/123`.

`alias foo='function bar(){echo "$1:a"};bar'` and executing `foo 123` produces `123:b`.

So different letters after the colon will have different results. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Your file (or whatever you getting `$1` from) is saved as a DOS text file instead of a UNIX one. That means it has a carriage return character at the end of each line. When printed, a carriage return sends the cursor to the left.

Comment: By the way -- why would you ever use an alias here instead of only defining a _function_ `foo`? It's only when defining git aliases that there's a reason to wrap functions that way; it's pointless for shell aliases.

Comment: Also, about the `function` keyword, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Another piece of advice: Use `set -x` in your script, or `bash -x your_script` when running it, to enable trace logging. That'll show you the commands being run, rendering the carriage returns as `\r` sequences inside `$''`-style quoting.